# How to give site page as an url to SearchResultPageURL property of sharepoint searchbox control?

Tags: sharepoint, search

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Control
     Id="SmallSearchInputBox"
     Sequence="24"
     ControlClass="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx"
     ControlAssembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
    <Property Name="SearchResultPageURL">**~Site/Pages/Customsearchresults.aspx**"></Property>
    <Property Name="FrameType">None</Property>
    <Property Name="DropDownMode">HideDD_NoScope</Property>
    <Property Name="TextBoxWidth">140</Property>
    <Property Name="ShowAdvancedSearch">false</Property>

  </Control>
</Elements>
```

The ~ operator doesnt work. I dont want to give an application page url.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by application page url ? Do you mean layouts page ? Why don't you give absolute url here...

Comment: Yup yes dont want to deploy my custom page into layouts. Wanted that page to be a sitepage.

Comment: Give it like that <Property Name="SearchResultPageURL">/search/results.aspx</Property>

Comment: it doesnt work at the site level. IE if i activate the feature at a site level.It should take somthing like http://localhost/site1/pages/customsearchresults.aspx.  but it takes http://localhost/Pages/Customsearchresults.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**true**

UseSiteDefaults property is a must if you want a custom site page to be the target searchresults page.